# Syntax where let (constant) behaves like a function. Can you explain?

Tags: ios, swift, function, constants, alamofire

I came acros this syntax while trying to overwrite a file in Swift, but I can't understand it, since it seems that the constant behaves like a function (I'm using Alamofire for networking):

```
 let destination: (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> (NSURL) = {
        (temporaryUrl, response)  in
        if response.statusCode == 200 {
            if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(pdfUrl.path!) {
                try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(pdfUrl)
            }
            return DocumentDirectoryUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pdfFileName)
        }
        else {
            return temporaryUrl
        }
    }
```

Here are the constants used in `destination`

```
    let DocumentDirectoryUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!)
    let pdfFileName = filename
    let pdfUrl = DocumentDirectoryUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pdfFileName)
```

I don't understand how it's working because `destination` is declared as a constant, but it behaves like a function. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: `destination` is a  "closure", and closures are explained in detail in the Swift book.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, functions are objects, just like integers, doubles, strings, and so on. So yes, you can absolutely assign a function to a constant. So that constant doesn't have a type "Int" or "Double" or "String" but in this case "(NSURL, NSURLHTTPResponse) -> NSURL".

You can have an array of functions, a dictionary with functions as values, a struct or class where one or more instance variables are functions, and so on.

Comment: Actually `Int(s)`, `Double(s)` and `String(s)` are not objects in Swift. They are structs.

Comment: In a wider sense where everything is an object... Like in C, where everything other than a bitfield is an object.

Comment: I admit that looking at the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html the word `Instance` is used in place of `Object` to indicate an instance of a class (as I thought instead). This because in Swift `Classes` and `Structs` are much closer in functionality than in other languages. However maybe the word `Type` is more appropriate to indicate `Classes`, `Structs` and `Enums`. Anyway +1 for your answer because the concept you expressed is very clearly.